# exporting scraped data to CSV with a specific column

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

My code is currently printing the result on command screen.

desired result (see attached screenshot): write the final output to CSV file in column 'a2'
and output the sku# to column 'a1'
the sku# always will be the text that comes after the 5th '/' in the url

here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv
def get_bullets(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
    content = soup.find('div', class_='js-productHighlights product-highlights c28 fs14 js-close')
    bullets = content.find_all('li', class_='top-section-list-item')
    for bullet in bullets:
     print(bullet.string)

get_bullets('https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1225875-REG/canon_1263c004_eos_80d_dslr_camera.html')
```

Desired Result:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


def get_bullets(url):
    sku = url.split('/')[5]
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
    content = soup.find('div', class_='js-productHighlights product-highlights c28 fs14 js-close')
    bullets = content.find_all('li', class_='top-section-list-item')

    bullets_text = '\n'.join([ bullet.text for bullet in bullets ])

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sku, bullets_text]], columns = ['sku','bullets'])
    temp_df.to_csv('path/filename.csv', index=False)


get_bullets('https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1225875-REG/canon_1263c004_eos_80d_dslr_camera.html')
```

Comment: Work like a charm. TY!